# Eliminar datos anteriores a una Hora

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla en donde guardo registros casi que cada segundo,lo que intento realizar es un trigger que al insertar en la tabla se dispare y elimine los registros anteriores a una hora para asi mantener el control de la tabla, se eliminar datos de un dia anterior o de un mes anterior, pero no conozco la funcion para eliminar datos especificamente de una hora atras a la hora actual

Esta es la funcion que uso para eliminar registros menores a 4 meses

```
Delete from tabla where fecha > DATEADD(mm,-4,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0 + DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE()) -1)))
```

Alguien tiene conocimiento sobre una funcion parecida, o sabe de alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diría que si la conoces, pero no has dado con el parámetro adecuado.

```
declare @table table (id int identity(1,1), fecha datetime)
declare @fecha datetime = getdate();
insert into @table (fecha)
values
(@fecha),
(dateadd(hour,-1,@fecha)),
(dateadd(hour,-2,@fecha)),
(dateadd(hour,-3,@fecha)),
(dateadd(hour,-4,@fecha)),
(dateadd(hour,-5,@fecha));

select * from @table

delete from @table where fecha < DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())

select * from @table
```

[image: Resultado de las dos selects]

No obstante, quizá te fuera mejor que un trigger, utilizar una tarea programada del agente del Sql server, o del programador de tareas de windows, quien realizase esa acción. Y podrías anotar en ellas, que ha realizado la tarea.

[Programar tareas con Agente Sql Server](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/17/agente-sql-programar-sentencias-sql/)

[Programar tareas con Task Scheduler](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/02/03/usar-el-programador-de-tareas-de-windows-para-ejecutar-codigo-sql-periodicamente/)

Answer (score 0):

Te complicas demasiado la existencia. Simplemente se usa un `DATEADD` para restar una hora a la fecha actual.

```
DELETE FROM tabla WHERE fecha < DATEADD(HH,-1, GETDATE());
```